# Running python with command line in java

Tags: java, python, process, sumo

The program is stuck at `p2.waitFor()` (I tested with printing strings before and after)

```
public void score() {
    this.toXML();
    try {
        Process p = Runtime
                    .getRuntime()
                    .exec("python sumocfg_maker.py Carrefour.net.xml Detectors.det.xml edgedata.csv -ef");
        p.waitFor();
        Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python simulation.py");

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String line = null;

                try {
                    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                        System.out.println(line);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        p2.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    
}
```

and `simulation.py` is

```
import os

os.system('cmd /c "sumo -c Simulation.sumocfg --duration-log.statistics --log duration.txt)
```

The `simulation.py` runs fine on its own. When I put the command in `simulation.py` in java, I get the same problem.

The `System.out.println(line);` prints out "Success" and then nothing
I left out code from `simulation.py` that saves a file that the java reads right after the `p2.wait()`, and without the `p2.wait()` the file never changes.

Comment: Is the thread stuck in an infinite loop? `line` is only `null` when the `BufferedReader` reaches `EOF`

Comment: Does this really make sense? `new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())`. It seems to me that `p` is already finished.

Answer (score 1):

You have

`BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));`

But you need

`BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));`

since p is already finished, the bufferedreader will wait but never receive anything.